# Building .NET web app for MC9090

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, windows-ce, barcode-scanner, motorola

I have to develop a `ASP.NET` application for `MC9090`. It has very simple views:

- A login view.
- A view with some buttons.
- And the buttons will go to views with the barcode scanning that when scanned will display some text on the same view.

The back end will be much more complex.

I have never worked with `MC9090` before, and before diving in, I am wondering how to render my views? I would prefer to just make `REST APIs` with `.NET` and have the browser on `MC9090` make `HTTP` calls to it. Our `MC9090` runs `Windows CE 5.0` and I read that `Windows CE 5.0` uses `IE6`. The `MC9090` only has `64 or 128 MB` of `RAM` too, according to its specs. Is `IE6` and that small amount of `RAM` capable of making ajax calls and hiding/creating simple `DOM` elements (just text and buttons)? Am I able to include older versions of `jQuery (1.x)` that supports `IE6` and have it run smoothly on the `MC9090`?

I could also use the `Razor View Engine`, but that is probably more heavyweight than `JavaScript`, right?

The scanner application, in this case, the web app, needs to be very quick. Users will be scanning barcodes one after another in quick succession. For each scan, my web app will make an ajax request to the server for some info about the barcode as well as for the server to process the barcode.

So my question is whether the `JavaScript` approach is feasible?